# Issues with OpenVPN server accepting connections but not allowing traffic

Tags: networking, server, vpn, firewall, openvpn

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a rooted Android box with Linux Deploy to make it a OpenVPN server. I have diligently followed the guide at https://nanashi07.blogspot.com/2017/...id-device.html and the one at https://www.digitalocean.com/communi...n-ubuntu-16-04 and I have used keys and certificates that do work correctly on a Windows server.

The OpenVPN client connects correctly to the server, but at that point it can't go outside. In facts, the only thing I managed to do from the client is ping 10.8.0.6 which is its own IP assigned by the VPN server, can't even ping the server itself. After studying a lot and spending 2 days playing around with configuration, I have come to the conclusion that I need to ask for some help. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

In particular, some things that I did (as I see they are often reason for a problem similar to mine) are:
modifying the /etc/sysctl.conf file, uncommenting

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

modified /etc/ufw/before.rules with

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

modified the the /etc/default/ufw with

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

and I also changed the default input policy to "Accept" for now, this was not required but should not be the cause of my problem.

The openvpn server configuration is

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Ifconfig now reads

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:2a:fe:48:63:81
          inet addr:192.168.0.174  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c62a:feff:fe48:6381/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:997126 (997.1 KB)  TX bytes:1110696 (1.1 MB)
          Interrupt:56

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00                      -00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:200 (200.0 B)
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I have an `auth SHA256` after the `cipher` directive but otherwise my config file is essentially the same as yours.  It's been so long since I set it up, I no longer remember the purpose of this directive. Your tun0 output is significantly different from mine, one that jumps out is the P-t-P.  Isn't that a different tunneling protocol than OpenVPN? P-t-P does not appear in my tun0 output.  Perhaps the problem is in your client settings?

Comment: Actually I think it's firewall problem or Linux component missing.I just installed PPTPD server, and that VPN has the same problem, client connects, sends lots of packets but receives very few, and traffic doesn't go out

Comment: I do not believe this will fix your problem but: In your server config file u write:`server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` and in your ufw rule u write `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` but it should be `-s 10.8.0.0/24` instead. It would be great if you could also post your clients config file.